# Change Hibernate's PersistentSet to HashSet

Tags: hibernate, persistent-set

I have a program that compares objects from 2 databases.

I have objects from 2 different databases and I have to compare them. The problem is that hibernate returns a `PersistentSet` and this causes the program to fail as it only supports Java Collections.

Is there an elegant way to change this `PersistentSet` to `HashSet`. I have already tried Introspector approach but it still seems not to work with this comparator.

Comment: What is the code you use for comparition?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not supposed to depend directly on the `PersistentSet` class, that is considered an internal implementation detail of Hibernate.

Instead, you should use the type `java.util.Set` in your Java code (which `PersistentSet` implements).

Just don't try to cast the `PersistentSet` to `HashSet`. Instead assign it to `java.util.Set`, as in all Hibernate code examples.

Comment: Hi, PersistentSet is returned from the database as there is a lazy association in the fetched object.

Comment: But `PersistentSet` implements `java.util.Set`.

Comment: Hi Gavin, The problem was the framework that does the comparison, it does not work fine when it is supplied with entities containing Persistence Sets.I have written a small code to remove persistent sets, following which code to compare object is working fine.